# Get a limited number of rows for each match in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like:

```
1 a a1 a2
1 b b1 b2
1 c c1 c2
1 d d1 d2
2 a a1 a2
2 b b1 b2
2 c c1 c2
3........
3........
........
........
n x x1 x2
n y y1 y2
n z z1 z2
```

From this, I want to get for each number(1,2,3,4....n) some specified number(say 2) of rows.

**Result:**

```
1 a a1 a2
1 b b1 b2
2 a a1 a2
2 b b1 b2
.........
.........
n x x1 x2
n y y1 y2
```

I am trying to do `group by` and `string_agg()`. But I can't limit it to a specified number.

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select nr, col1, col2, col3
from (
  select nr, col1, col2, col3,  
         row_number() over (partition by nr order by col1) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where rn <= 2;
```

If you want to influence *which* rows are returned, you can adjust the `order by` that defines the ordering of the rows in the window function.